# Error when trying to connect postgres database with prisma and docker compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker-compose, fastapi, prisma

I am trying to make a connection between a postgres database with docker compose, and a backend application with python, fastapi and prisma, but when making the connection between containers it generates the following error:

```
20.07 Environment variables loaded from .env
20.07 Prisma schema loaded from schema.prisma
20.08 Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "test", schema "public" at "db:5432"
25.13 Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`
25.13
25.13 Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`5432`.
```

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
   server:
     build: .
     ports:
       - 80:80
     depends_on:
       -db

   DB:
     image: postgres
     restart: always
     shm_size: 128mb
     ports:
       - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
     environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
       POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12.2

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app
COPY ./.env /code/.env
COPY ./schema.prisma /code/schema.prisma

RUN prism db push

CMD [ "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80" ]
```

my environment variables:

```
POSTGRES_USER = "test"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "test"
POSTGRES_DB = "test"
POSTGRES_PORT = "5432"

DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://test:test@db:5432/test'
```

And this is the prism schema:

```
// database
datasource db {
     provider = "postgresql"
     url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

//generator
generator client {
     provider = "prisma-client-py"
     recursive_type_depth = 5
}
```

Comment: In your compose file, try naming your database service `db` instead of `DB`.